# XQuery - replace xml values with decrypted value (db2)

Tags: xml, db2, xquery

I have a block of XML which I need to scan and replace all encrypted values with a decrytped values. I have a decrypt function, and the xml elements that need to be decrypted will have an attribute indicated they are encrypted. Not all of the values are encypted, and the XML returned must be identical to the starting XML apart from new decrypted values. 
I can think if anyway to do this.  i am new to xquery.

example xml below

```html
<book>
  <title encrypted=true>0234534rdf;skdlfsd</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

```html
<book>
  <title encrypted=true>Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that on Db2 for z/OS or on Linux/Unix/Windows? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to replace an element which says (correctly) that its content is encrypted with an element whose content is decrypted but which says (falsely) that the content is still encrypted?  Find the designer who specified this behavior and administer severe counseling.

Comment: The code will be running in the database as a database package , so I have been trying to use xquery, but I am a bit stumped on how to go about this.  Main problem is that I will not no beforehand which colums are encrypted, so the procedure needs to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Below should be an xQuery 1.0 safe solution. It could be more compact, but is left like this for full review.

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:encrypt($node){
  'an encrypted value'
};

declare function local:decrypt($node){
  'a decrypted value'
};


declare function local:traverse-and-encrypt($nodes as node()*) as node()*{
  for $n in $nodes 
  return if($n/@encrypted = 'true')
    then element{fn:node-name($n)}{
      for $a in $n/@*
        return if(fn:local-name($a) = 'encrypted')
          then attribute {'encrypted'} {'false'}
          else $a,
      local:decrypt($n/text())
    }
    else if($n/@encrypted = 'false')
      then element{fn:node-name($n)}{
        for $a in $n/@*
          return if(fn:local-name($a) = 'encrypted')
            then attribute {'encrypted'} {'true'}
            else $a,
        local:encrypt($n/text())
      }
      else element{fn:node-name($n)}{
        $n/@*,
        $n/text(),
        for $child in $n/*
          return local:traverse-and-encrypt($child)
      }  
};

let $doc := 
<books>
  <book>
    <title encrypted="true">0234534rdf;skdlfsd</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title encrypted="false">Another book</title>
    <author test='testing attributes'>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</books>

return local:traverse-and-encrypt($doc)
```

returns:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title encrypted="false">a decrypted value</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
         <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
       <title encrypted="true">an encrypted value</title>
       <author test="testing attributes">J K. Rowling</author>
       <year>2005</year>
       <price>29.99</price>
       </book>
</books>
```